# How to access TElement of IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> returned by GroupBy() in method call syntax

Tags: c#, linq

Using Linq's `GroupBy()` method, returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` type.

At this time, I wnat to return an anonymous type that matches `TElement` to `TKey` using `Select()` in method call syntax.

Here's the data we use in this question.

```cs
public class Pet
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>
  { 
    new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
    new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
    new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 },
    new Pet { Name="Daisy", Age=4 } 
  };
```

I can acheive what I want by nesting `foreach` in the following `methodCallSyntax`.

```cs
var methodCallSyntax = pets.GroupBy(pet => pet.Age, pet => pet.Name);

foreach (var grouping in methodCallSyntax)
{
  foreach (var element in grouping)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {grouping.Key}, Element: {element}");
  }
}
```

But I want to use `foreach` only once.

```cs
var methodCallSyntax =
  pets
    .GroupBy(pet => pet.Age, pet => pet.Name)
    // .Select(grouping => new {grouping.Key, Element = grouping.});

foreach (var item in methodCallSyntax)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Element: {item.Element}");
}
```

But as you can see I don't know what to fill out `Select()`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @YongShun No. It should return `Name`.

Comment: Do you really need a `.GroupBy`? or just an `.OrderBy`?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The problem is part of the study, and it is now resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SelectMany after GroupBy, and use a Select inside of SelectMany.

SelectMany transforms a multi-dimensional collection into a single sequence. The inner Select will return a collection, and SelectMany will transform all those values from Select into a single collection.

```
var all = pets
    .GroupBy(pet => pet.Age, pet => pet.Name)
    .SelectMany(group => group
        .Select(name => new { key = group.Key, value = name })
    );
```

Usage

```
foreach (var item in all)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.key}, Element: {item.value}");
}
```

Comment: Wow, when I was thinking about it again after writing the question, I thought I could use `SelectMany()`, but I didn't know how to implement it. But you did it! Thank you.